# How can I put a couple edited class files into a forge mod?

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I am trying to get the Signs Advanced GUI mod working on **1.10.2**. When you download the mod, all that you get is 2 `.class` files and a `.txt` document with no instructions.

I'm wondering if there is a way to get those 2 `.class` files into a forge mod to override the `.class` files that they're supposed to replace.

On the website I got the mod from, it told me to go into to the `%appdata%` folder, the `.minecraft` folder, and then the bin folder. Which now would be the versions folder. I opened up the `1.10.2.jar` file with WinRAR, deleted the `META-INF` folder, and put the `.class` files with the others. The problem is that if you tamper with Minecraft's class files, the version becomes corrupt and it re-downloads it, therefore undoing what you just changed.

I have a Java environment set up with Eclipse.

Comment: Could you may be give a source for where you got the mod, 
I can't seam to find any trust worthy sources for this mod. 
I am guessing that you got it from one of those shady sites
 and therefor recommend to not use the mod.

Comment: I got it from this site http://www.9minecraft.net/sign-advanced-gui-mod/

Comment: Yeah, wouldn't use any of their mods.
The Quark mods looks like it has a Sign Editing feature since 1.9, not sure if it's what you are looking for but [https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/quark]

Comment: The Quark mod is exactly what I'm looking for with the redesign sign gui, but sadly, the sign gui is only available for 1.12.2. Thank you for your help though, I will be using that mod for 1.12.2 minecraft from now on.

Answer (score 2):

## You can't.

Forge mods don't allow you to edit base vanilla classes *by design* because allowing base class edits is what makes mods incompatible with each other.

Depending on the type of changes, it would be possible to achieve the same functionality in another way. However some may be more difficult or more round about and I can't say for sure without knowing what kinds of changes the original mod was making.

Comment: Isn't this possible with a coremod though?

Comment: 1) don't write coremods unless you already know how to do it correctly, 2) no, because that's not how coremods are written, 3) don't write coremods.

Comment: Ah, well what the mod did was change the GUI of writing signs. It had an easier design where you could mouse over the text on the sign, copy and paste, it even showed the number of characters left on a line. I can imagine that it won't be the easiest thing to make, but writing signs in minecraft is so tedious, make 1 mistake and you have to break the sign and re-write everything.

Comment: Forge lets you override gui screens easily.